# Lenovo x1 carbon touchpad accuracy

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I just installed ubuntu 10.04 on my x1 carbon. Everything seems to work well except the touchpad. It seems that every time I move the curser to click on something, it jumps few pixels away. I accidentally closed windows I've been working on for that reason. otherwise, scrolling and tapping is working just fine. I came cross this page which I think identify my issue : http://code.technically.us/post/50837506478/senistive-touchpads-and-ubuntu . However, I can't understand what the author means by "softlink this file into :" . Does anyone have this issue or even a solution ? maybe try to explain that page in understandable way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means to create a file someplace with the content specified, and then create a softlink (aka shortcut, alias, etc) to the file in the directory /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ or you could just create the file in that directory directly. The X server looks in that directory for additional config files. It's done that way so users can add stuff like that without disrupting the normal default settings.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. It's clear now but I have one more question. under the xorg.conf.d directory files that hold names such as  50-synaptics.conf and 51-synaptics-quirks.conf ; with number such as 50 and 51, do I have to name my file e.g. 10-name.conf ?

Comment: Usually those type of files are run in sequential or alphabetic order. It's not a standard so much as a convention, so some programs might be picky about names, others not. To be on the safe side, I'd use a name like 90-touchpad.conf

Comment: somehow the script in that page missed up my settings. I still have this annoying issue where I tend to e.g. minimize window by clicking (-) and the curser moves to hit (x) and close the window instead. Any idea ?

Comment: Did you run the command he suggests: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false` ? Maybe try moving those other synaptics.conf files out of the directory in case there are some conflicting directives.

Comment: still no luck even with that command. I notice after running the script, the cursor stops many times and become more heavier to move. So, I had to delete the file I created.

Comment: Did you look at the contents of the other files that may be relevant in there? Maybe you can look at the file the guy made and the ones in there and come up with something that works by editing.

Comment: the files are all different. I tried to tweak this file to serve my need but unfortunately I'm back to square one. Right now I'm using trackpoint since it's more accurate. I don't know how other x1 carbon users handle this issue. maybe they just ignore it ?